# "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" Running java using cmd but getting error

Tags: java, cmd

Running java using cmd following commands but getting error

```
java -cp %etc_folder%%service%%library%
```

i did set up environment variable for etc_folder, service, library

```
library envi: target\service_service-05.2015.jar
```

I check the folder jar file is in folder.

getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: target\service_service-05/2015/jar;
caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: target\service_service-05.2015.jar;
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I think it's replacing "." to "/"

not sure why, can anyone please help with this. 
Thank in advanced!!

Comment: If I read that right you are executing java -cp target\service_service-05.2015.jar?  If so it will not work. (1) jar are run using 'java -jar' (2) 'java -jar' is mutually exclusive with 'java -cp' i.e. no -cp with jars (3) the jars internal manifest should be stating the main entrypoint  which will get executed when you use the -jar switch

Comment: Can you "echo %etc_folder%%service%%library%" to verify the value ? I think there is a space an so java think "target\service_service-05/2015/jar" is a main class.

Comment: oh, I see, you think that is not his whole execution command. Would be nice if he showed the whole execution command with vars expanded

Comment: Sorry about that, this is out of "echo %etc_folder%%service%%library%" --> "etc";"target/service_service-05.2015.jar;""com.xml.XML etc/xml_file.xml"

Comment: I am also getting same thing with 'library as well: etc/xml_file/xml'

Comment: Looks like somethign weird going on with windoze variable expansion. Java will not change the path parameters you give it. Try running the command as you expect the variables to expand, i.e. instead of java -cp %var% do java -cp \somepath\some.jar yadah yadah (obviously code it correctly). Then if it works, start going backwards from there adding one env var at a time to the comamnd to get it right.

Comment: tried that still getting same thing..

Answer (score 0):

You should execute Java as following pattern:

```
java -cp $(echo /opt/path/lib/*.jar| tr ' ' ':') com.xxx.xxx.MainClass
```

All your jar putting into `/opt/path/lib/`,
`com.xxx.xxx.MainClass` is which class you have `main()` function.

Comment: can you copy the command you executed, and unzip the jar to check if the class there? with correct package name?

Comment: and when you try, please don't use env, directly use the path.

Comment: I am getting error that, failed to load main class manifest attribute fromm .jar file

Comment: java -jar "some .jar" requires the jar is a executable jar. But the command I get to you, the jar could be a normal jar.

Comment: I am not really sure how to put your command.. can you please give me example? java -cp $(echo /target/service_service-05.2015.jar | tr  ' ' ':')..like this?

Comment: no,just "java -cp /target/service_service-05.2015.jar com.xxx.xxx.MainClass", if you have only one jar.

Comment: and also.. not only jar file but for other environment variable i am having same problem. set library = target\service_service-05.2015.jar ,, set service =  com.xml.XML etc/xml_file.xml  and when i do java -cp %library%%service% getting error for xml_file.xml as well --> 'etc\xml_file/xml'

Comment: I think java -cp /target/service_service-05.2015.jar com.xxx.xxx.MainClass is working.. thank you sir.. one more quick question to fine Mainclass.. have to unjar that file?

Comment: that's a way, or use some IDE to open it, like IDEA. You could see decompilation of the classes. then you can find out which is the main class.

Comment: ohh ok thank you sir.. can you please also help with other environment variable.. like set service = etc_folder\xml_file.xml, when i do java -cp getting error etc_folder\xml_file\xml..

Comment: why you need this? any documentation tell you to do that?